# PHP, $_GET unfriendly URL characters and ignoring index names

Tags: php, get, tree

I have a PHP tree class that simulates a directory structure. I would like to implement a function that uses `$_GET` with any number of parameters and if the parameters align with the tree structure's directory titles, then that directory is the initial directory displayed on the website. For example, if someone wrote:

`.../index.php?dir1=Foo&dir2=Bar`

Then it would search the tree's root for children named `Foo`, then `Foo`'s children for a child named `Bar`, and so on. On a side note, it doesn't matter to me what the `dir1` / `dir2` are, they could be anything, I'm only interested in what they those indices point to.

My questions then are:

- Some of titles within the tree have characters that are possibly URL
  unfriendly like spaces, `.`, or HTML codes (like `&rsquo;`). Are
  there limitations to this and should to write a conversion
  function to do my comparisons?
- What would be the best way to ignore the index names (like `dir1`)
  and only check what they point to (like `Foo`)?

**Edit**: A more concrete example could someone writing: `.../index.php?dir1=Web Work&dir2=awebsite.com`

Comment: Special characters will be encoded with `%`, and PHP will take care of decoding them before filling in `$_GET`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Special characters should be [percent-encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). PHP will take care of decoding them before filling in `$_GET`.

You can use `foreach($_GET as $dirname)`. This will just step through the values, ignoring the keys.

```
$curlevel = $tree;
foreach ($_GET as $dirname) {
  $found = false;
  foreach ($curlevel->children as $child) {
    if ($child->name == $dirname) {
      $curlevel = $child;
      $found = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!$found) {
    // default to index page
  }
}
```

Comment: This idea occurred to me, but then I'd be doing n^2 comparisons between `$_GET` and my tree (although, admittedly this is not that significant as `count($_GET)` will be small). Can I ignore the indices in another way?

Comment: Why n^2? The first dir should be the first level, the second dir should be the second level, and so on.

Comment: Why are you doing it this way, instead of something like `?path=foo/bar/whatever`?

Comment: Because if I used `foreach ($_GET as $dirname)` then I'd be comparing it with each `foreach ($tree->children as $child)` when I only need to compare `$_GET[i]` ideally.

Comment: When I write `print_r($_GET)` for URL `.../index.php?a/b/c` I get `Array ( [a/b/c] => )`, not sure how to implement your comment.

Comment: It should be `path=a/b/c`, then `$_GET` will be `Array ( [path] => "a/b/c" )`.

Comment: Either way, searching the tree is the same. You use a `for` or `foreach` loop. It shouldn't be n^2, because you're only seaching 1 level for each element. See my updated answer.

Comment: The updated answer appears to be n^2... it is every `$_GET` against every child of the current tree node in the worst case. **Edit**: perhaps it is n^2 due to my implementation, I can't check full path names, just each child against `$_GET[i]`

Comment: No it isn't. Look at the way I step down through the tree with `$curlevel`. Each iteration just compares the current element of `$_GET` with the names in the the current level of the tree.

Comment: It would be better if your tree class had a method to get a child by name directly.

Comment: Just realized I should have mentioned that I was thinking of n as `count($_GET)` and `count(average children per node)`, my bad

Answer (score 1):

There is something like URL encoding. Your webserver and PHP handle the decoding for you.

Check out this function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

To cycle through the items, as @Barmar suggests, you can use `foreach($_GET as $arg=>$dirname)`. This will just step through the values, with the keys in `$arg`.

Also, be careful with letting users enter arbitrary paths.

Comment: If the user enters an an invalid path name (one that my tree doesn't have) then I just ignore `$_GET` and go to the homepage.